# Centering a <ul> using CSS

Tags: html, css, html-lists, center

I have some navigation links at the top of the page that I am having trouble placing in the centre of the screen. Can anybody suggest where I'm going wrong in the CSS?

Image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdrEc.png

Here's the CSS:

```
#nav {
list-style-type:none;
text-align:center
}

ul li {
display:inline-block;
border-radius:10px;
background:#EEE;
margin:5px;
}

li a {
float:left;
padding:30px;
text-decoration:none;
color:black;
text-shadow: 1px 1px #DDD;
border-radius:10px;
box-shadow:3px 3px black;
}

li a:hover {
background:#CCC;
color:#333;
}

li a:active {
background:#555;
color:white;
text-shadow: 1px 1px #000;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick demo of how to center a UL: http://jsfiddle.net/73Mum/1/

```
<div class="wrap">
 <ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li>four</li>
    <li>five</li>
 </ul>
</div>

.wrap {
 text-align:center;
 background:#999;
 padding:100px 0;
}

ul {
 width:500px;
 margin:0 auto;
}
ul li {
 display:inline-block;
 padding:10px;
 background:#ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi actually i have updated your **css** now i hope this work will for you :-

**[DEMO](http://tinkerbin.com/WCGuCvbP)**

**CSS**

```
#nav {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #B8B8B8;
    height: 400px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 40px 0;
    width: 400px;
}

ul li {
display:inline;

}

li a {
text-decoration:none;
color:black;
text-shadow: 1px 1px #DDD;
border-radius:10px;
background:#EEE;
margin:5px;
padding:30px;
box-shadow:3px 3px black;
}

li a:hover {
background:#CCC;
color:#333;
}

li a:active {
background:#555;
color:white;
text-shadow: 1px 1px #000;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!, it just needed a little padding for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping these `<ul>`-tags with a `<div style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto">`.
This way you center all `<ul>`-tags at once.

If "1,2,3,4,5" in your picture are the ul-elements and #nav is the id of your surrounding div, you can just add `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto` to #nav in your stylesheet.

Comment: I've tried that, but there is still a gap to the left of the list items. i dont think the problems lies in my html either:

Comment: <body>
<div id="all">
<ul id="nav"><li>
<a href="#">1</a></li><li>
<a href="#">2</a></li><li>
<a href="#">3</a></li><li>
<a href="#">4</a></li><li>
<a href="#">5</a></li>
</ul>
<p id="para">qefniqpefin pqienf ipqnef pinqefin iefpqifn3qp34htq08 24987ty q3t y9q74yt9-2qyt48 wrahug 98arwg08y24 24tu08 08=ywg wrg8 2 h424tohu owug wgihwE[IFU Q
EFOi qiogh oiH WOUH WRUIGH94P8HWA9PRUGH P9UAHRG9P84YG 289YHTIO[ FB8YAIUHR OIH24TJRNETH7 GYDB 098NY0BYR JWOJF08H</p>
<button class="colorButton" onclick="colorChange()">Color</button>

</div>
</body>